# How to delete record using below condition in sql

Tags: sql, delete-row, delete-record

I have the following tables and I need to remove the rows that satisfy a given condition.

Please help me.

Table: `Product`

```
productId productname datecreated
1         sample1     20/01/2012
2         sample1     20/01/2012
3         sample2     20/02/2012
4         sample2     20/02/2012
5         sample2     20/09/2012
6         sample1     20/08/2012
```

Table: `Category`

```
categoryid categoryname
1          cat1
2          cat2
3          cat3
```

Table: `ProductCategory`

```
postid  categoryid
1         1
4         2
```

Now I want to delete the rows which have the `count > 1 group by productname` and `datecreated` from first table and also the rows that are not contained in the `productcategory` table

i.e, I want to remove the

```
  ProductId 2 and ProductId 3
```

because it has the same `ProductName` with same `DateCreated` and also is not contained in the `ProductCategory` Table

thanks in advance

Comment: There is an error in one of your tables. ProductCategory should contain 1, 2 and 3 in the categoryid column, instead of the category names.

Comment: thanks LugiEdlCarno. I edited the question.

Comment: So is answer was helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
delete Product
from Product as P
where
    P.productId not in (select T.postid from ProductCategory as T) and
    exists
    (
        select T.*
        from Product as T
        where
            T.productId <> P.productId and
            T.productname = P.productname and
            T.datecreated = P.datecreated
    )
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df565/1)</kbd>**

Comment: if the productname and datecreated are same and it has two rows in the table then the count will be considered

Answer (score 0):

You could first do this to remove all products that are not inside the ProductCategory table:

STEP 1

```
Delete from Product 
Where productId not IN(select productId from ProductCategory)
```

And then if you still want to remove duplicates from your Product table you could try this:

STEP 2

```
Select productname, datecreated, Count(*)
Into TheKeys
from Product 
Group by productname, datecreated
Having Count(*)>1
```

This TheKeys table would contain the duplicate values

STEP 3

```
Select DISTINCT Product.*
Into TheRows
From Product, TheKeys
Where Product.productname = TheKeys.productname
And Product.datecreated = TheKeys.datecreated
```

Table TheRows contains all the corresponding rows

STEP 4

```
Delete Product 
From Product, TheKeys
Where Product.productname = TheKeys.productname
and Product.datecreated = TheKeys.datecreated
```

this would delete all the duplicate rows

and lastly put the unique rows back into the table with this:

STEP 5

```
Insert into Product (productId, productname, datecreated)
Select * From TheRows
```

NOTE: If you dont mind having products that do not belong to any category 
You could leave out the first step and do this Right AFTER STEP 3

```
Delete From TheRows
Where productId not In(Select productId from ProductCategory)
```

and then continue with STEP 4